# How to make a text to fade out and only get some letters and create a new word in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, splash-screen, fade

I am trying to make a launch splash screen for my iOS project. I want to show my service full name and then just get the first letters of each word with the other words getting faded away.

For example

Service Involvement Expenditure - > Intially

S I E -> Letters to be displayed after other texts fade away.

[image: Splash Screen]

Please help me to make something like the above gif ?

Comment: can you get the animation done in Adobe after effects?  perhaps you could use https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios - I've never used it but this seems like the perfect application for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the text and then fetch the first character of each substring just like that

```
var YourString: String = "Service Involvement Expenditure"
let sunstringArray = YourString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

var firstString: String = sunstringArray [0]    //Service 
var secondString: String = sunstringArray [1]   //Involvement 
var thirdString: String = sunstringArray [2]    //Expenditure
```

now to get only the first charcter use below code

```
 var firstletter = String(firstString.characters.first!)    //S
  var secondletter = String(secondString.characters.first!)    //I
  var thirdletter = String(thirdString.characters.first!)    //E

var fullFirstChar = firstletter + secondletter + thirdletter //SIE

 UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                            self.fullFirstChar .alpha = 1.0
                        },
                                       completion: {

                                        (finished: Bool) -> Void in

                                    // Fade out
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                                        self.fullFirstChar .alpha = 0.0
                                    },
                                                   completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
                                                    AppInfo.instance.isAnimationCompleted = true
                                    })
                    })
```

i hope this will help

Comment: Thanks a lot , this was really helpful, I just made a little simple version and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIView.animate

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

     label.alpha = 0
})
```

Thats for fade out animation, you can do everything you want inside animation block.

You can add an extension to UIView to access easy fadeout

```
extension UIView {

    func fadeOut(duration: TimeInterval) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {

             self.alpha = 0
        }
    }
}
```

then use it:

```
label.fadeOut()
```

As i said, you can do everything you want inside animation block, so you can change text, and when it finish move them and those things. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input